# AIDL extends interface

Tags: android, inheritance, aidl

i got a architecture design with an Interface

```
public interface IExchange  {
    abstract String transmit(String);
}
```

And i have to develop an Android application with 2 activities that exchange data, and my application has to be based on this architecture.
I thought to a AIDL, which would have to extend IExchange, but AIDL doesn't support inheritance.
What would be the alternative to this problem?
Tx

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to exchange data between two `Activity` instances, there's no need to define an interface like this.  In fact, it would be difficult to use it beyond some special cases.  Only one `Activity` can be in the running state at a time (unless using something like multi-window or PIP), but there's no need to define an interface for this.  Just add a `String` extra to an `Intent` and send the `Intent` from one `Activity` to the other.

Use of AIDL is meant for specialized `Service` type components and is much more involved.

Comment: tx but i have to implement this interface, the architecture is imposed. There would be no alternative to the change of architecture? And yes, the exchange of data can be processed between a service and a activity.

Comment: Your question was not about a `Service` and `Activity` sharing data, it was about two activities.  AIDL is central to how binder interfaces are declared and used in Android (especially at the Java level), and this is used by `Service` type components.  When you declare an interface in AIDL, it will cause boilerplate code to be generated for that class (`IExchange` in your case) which is derived from `IInterface`. See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more details about using bound services.